# Upload the image with socket io file - upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to upload files with socketio-file-upload, in which i found an error
==  file:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: SocketIOFileUpload is not defined  ===

my code is here

```
   const socket = io();
    socket.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    const uploader = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);
    uploader.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("fileUpload"));
    uploader.addEventListener("start", (event) => {
      event.file.meta.extension = "csv";
    });
    document
      .getElementById("file_button")
      .addEventListener("click", uploader, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including the SocketIOFileUpload object on client side.

In your node server if you are using `socketio-file-upload` like this on the express server:

```
var siofu = require("socketio-file-upload");
var app = express()
    .use(siofu.router)
    .listen(8000);

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    var uploader = new siofu();
    uploader.dir = "/path/to/save/uploads";
    uploader.listen(socket);
});
```

then the package `socketio-file-upload` exposes client side script at base url. You have to import that script on client side like so:

```
<script src="/siofu/client.js"></script>
```

Note the name of the script is related to the object you create in your express app.